# joining two from with an expression<func<>>

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression

Is it possible to join two `from` based on a local expression variable?

ex;

```
 var query = from t in context.table1
             from a in context.anothertable1.Where(x => t.id == a.id)
             select new {a,t};
```

on line 2, the Where clause `.Where(x => t.id == a.id)` how would you move it into an expression?

I know i can do this;

```
Expression<Func<anothertable1, bool>> test = x => x.field1 == 1;
```

and It would work here;

```
 var query = from t in context.table1
             from a in context.anothertable1
                              .Where(x => t.id == a.id)
                              .Where(test)
             select new {a,t};
```

and everything work and the sql query generated is as expected.

I can't figure out how to do the same with the other `where`.

**EDIT**

a more complex example, i anonymized it so it might not compile

```
var listOfMinMaxtable1 = (from n in context.table1.Where(table1Filter)
                           group n by n.table1_Number into grp
                           select new MinMaxtable1()
                           {
                               table1_Id_Max = grp.Max(x => x.table1_Id),
                               table1_Id_Min = grp.Min(x => x.table1_Id),
                               table1_Number = grp.Key
                           });

var listtable2 = (from t in context.table2 
                              group t by t.table2_Id into grp
                              select new table2()
                              {
                                  table2  = grp,
                                  table2_Id = grp.Key
                              });

var query = from MinMax in listOfMinMaxtable1

                 //inner join **reference 1**                    
             from table3 in context.table3
                             .Where(x => x.table_Number == MinMax.table_Number)
                             .Where(noticeMasterFilter) //a working expression<func<>>

                 //inner join **reference 2**
             from Lasttable1 in context.table1
                              .Where(x => x.table_Id == MinMax.table_Id_Max)

                 //left join **reference 3**
             from Firsttable1 in context.table1
                              .Where(x => x.table_Id == MinMax.table_Id_Min)
                              .Where(firstNoticeFilter) //a working expression<func<>>
                              .DefaultIfEmpty()

                 //left join **reference 4**
             from Lasttable2 in listtable2
                                .Where(x => x.table_Id == MinMax.table_Id_Max)
                                .SelectMany(x => x.table2)
                                .Where(x => x.table2_Id == 123)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.table_Id)
                                .Take(1)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty()
```

if you find //left join **reference 3** in the code above

that where clause; `.Where(x => x.table_Id == MinMax.table_Id_Min)`
might be sometime; `.Where(x => x.table_Id == MinMax.table_Id_Max)`

I could just copy/paste the whole `from` and change the where clause while adding noop pattern (an expression that return false and this make entity framework remove the whole thing so it doesn't affect the generated sql/result) with an expression on both `from`

for reference(this is noise to the question), the noop expression that i'm talking about is;

```
   Expression<Func<table1, bool>> includeFrom= x => false;
```

and would be used like

```
                 //left join **reference 3**
             from Firsttable1 in context.table1
                              .Where(x => x.table_Id == MinMax.table_Id_Min)
                              .Where(firstNoticeFilter) //a working expression<func<>>
                              .Where(includeFrom) //<--- this line make it a noop if the expression stay false
                              .DefaultIfEmpty()
```

but I don't want to do this if it's possible to make a custom expression that would go into the `.Where()`

Comment: Are you actually trying to achieves linq's built in method syntax for Join? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user6144226, yes, i'm trying to make a join while mixing query syntax and method syntax, the join would be dynamic

Comment: If you want to do a `Join`, why are you using `SelectMany` instead of `Join`?

Comment: @Servy, the code above is a simple example but I'm filtering the source at the, yes, SelectMany there is many more SelectMany and each join got a custom where clause and sometime groupby and order / firstordefault / defaultifempty(leftjoin) and top (take), the generated sql is proper and behave like it should

Comment: None of that explains why you can't use a `Join`.

Comment: @Servy i will add a more complex example in a few minutes, i'm "anonymizing" the code but mostly i want to know how to build an expression that would replace the "hardcoded" where condition that link 2 tables (selectmany)

Comment: @Servy i added a more complex example, i'm not sure if it help explaining why i'm doing what i'm doing

Comment: @Servy, im back into my question. How would you do the complex example above with Join ?

Comment: @Fredou What problems do you have using it?  You pass in the two tables, and the two keys to join on, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an expression based on one type, you can create a combined type and use that for your `where` expression.

**Two Table Combined Type**

```
public class TwoTableDto
{
  public Table1 t { get; set; }
  public Table2 a { get; set; }
}
```

**Query without expression**

```
var query = (from t in context.table1
             from a in context.anothertable1
             select new TwoTableDto { t = t, a = a })
             .Where(x => x.t.id == x.a.id);
```

**Expression**

```
Expression<Func<TwoTableDto, bool>> expr = x => x.t.id == x.a.id;
```

**Query with expression**

```
 var query = (from t in context.table1
              from a in context.anothertable1
              select new TwoTableDto { t = t, a = a })
              .Where(expr);
```